# Getting Files Using Chrome App API

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, asynchronous, google-chrome-app

I have the following code:

```
    decodeFile = function(theFile, arrayBuffer) {
        var song = new FileDecoder().decodeFile(theFile.type, arrayBuffer);
        if (song !== null) {
            fileList.push(song);
        }
    },
    fileCreated = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            decodeFile(file, e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    },
    readDirItems = function(items) {
        var i, item,
            length = items.length;
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            item = items[i];
            if (item.isFile) {
                item.file(fileCreated, errorCallback);
            }
        }
     };
//init
uploadInput.addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: "openDirectory"}, function(chosenDir) {
        var dirReader,
            getFilesInDirectory = function() {
                dirReader.readEntries(readDirItems, errorCallback);
            };
        if (chosenDir && chosenDir.isDirectory) {
            dirReader = chosenDir.createReader();
            getFilesInDirectory();
        }
    });
});
```

How I expected this to work is that in `readDirItems` I would loop though all the items and for each fileEntry call the `file` method and enter the `fileCreated` callback. However this only happens for the first file. If I breakpoint in `fileCreated` it is only entered once. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Your code was quite a bit more complicated than necessary for this question, so here's a simpler version. It's possible that the bug was fixed in the process of cleaning up the code.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "20184022",
  "description": "Answer to Stack Overflow question 20184022.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "31",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",

  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    {"fileSystem": ["directory"]}
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {});
});
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="iterate.js"></script></head>
<body><button id="iterate">Iterate</button></body>
</html>
```

iterate.js

```
window.onload = function() {
  var errorCallback = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  document.querySelector("#iterate").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: "openDirectory"}, function(dir) {
      if (dir && dir.isDirectory) {
        var reader = dir.createReader();
        reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
          for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i) {
            console.log("entry is " + entries[i].fullPath);
          }
        }, errorCallback);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

... and a sample run:

```
entry is /20184022/manifest.json iterate.js:13
entry is /20184022/iterate.js iterate.js:13
entry is /20184022/main.js iterate.js:13
entry is /20184022/main.html iterate.js:13
```

I recommend that you gradually change your code to match this sample, then once your code changes from broken to fixed, determine what the problem was and update your question to point out the error.

Comment: I agree that your code is much cleaner, however my issue is that when looping though files in `readEntries` for each entry I call (in your case) `entries[i].file(fileCreated, errorCallback)` and only the first file goes into the fileCreated method.

Comment: I'd recommend gradually introducing your specific functionality to this sample, stopping when it breaks, and figuring out what's wrong. I came across this question because of the google-chrome-app tag. I don't have any special knowledge about the HTML5 portion of your question.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was but after moving things around a little bit like you suggested the code seems to work. Though its a little weird, if I breakpoint in `fileCreated` above it still only gets entered once, however all files in the directory are read.